# Mocking super method call using easymock/powermock

Tags: spring, powermock, easymock

I integrated easymock with my Spring project and performed most of the unit tests. But got an issue with not able to mock the super method. When I run my test class it says method not supported.

Any idea what's going wrong as I tried my best for last couple of days and not able to get any clue on how to mock the super method.

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Authentication method not supported: 
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:71)
    at com.dashboard.core.CustomAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(CustomAuthenticationFilter.java:20)
    at com.dashboard.core.CustomAuthenticationFilterTest.testAttemptAuthentication(CustomAuthenticationFilterTest.java:64)
```

Class which is subject to testing:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import com.dashboard.domain.ApplicationConstant;

public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        String username = request.getParameter("j_username");
        String password = request.getParameter("j_password");
        if(isValidUsername(username) && isValidPassword(password) ){
            return super.attemptAuthentication(request, response);
        }
        throw new BadCredentialsException(ApplicationConstant.CREDENTIALS_NOT_FORMAT.getValue());
    }

    private static boolean isValidUsername(String username){
        return !StringUtils.isEmpty(username) && username.matches(ApplicationConstant.USERNAME_PATTERN.getValue());
    }

    private static boolean isValidPassword(String password){
        return !StringUtils.isEmpty(password) && password.matches(ApplicationConstant.PWD_PATTERN.getValue());
    }
}
```

My Test class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.easymock.EasyMockRunner;
import org.easymock.EasyMockSupport;
import org.easymock.Mock;
import org.easymock.TestSubject;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@RunWith(EasyMockRunner.class)
public class CustomAuthenticationFilterTest extends EasyMockSupport{

    @TestSubject
    CustomAuthenticationFilter customAuthenticationFilter  = new CustomAuthenticationFilter();

    @Mock
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

    @Test
    public void testAttemptAuthentication() throws Exception{   
        MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        request.setParameter("j_username", "Sundar1234");
        request.setParameter("j_password", "Sundar1234$$");
        MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
        SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> updatedAuthorities = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
        updatedAuthorities.add(authority);
        User user = new User("Sundar1234", "Sundar1234$$", updatedAuthorities);
        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user,null);
        EasyMock.expect(usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(request, response)).andReturn(auth);
        EasyMock.replay(usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter);
        Assert.assertNotNull(customAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(request, response));
        EasyMock.verify(usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` is a base class, not an injected dependency. Normally, you can workaround that by using a [partial mock](http://easymock.org/user-guide.html#mocking-partial). But you can't since `CustomAuthenticationFilter` is calling `super.attemptAuthentication` which can't be mocked.

Your solutions are:

1. Test `CustomAuthenticationFilter` and its superclass altogether
2. Use a delegation pattern instead

But because of the current Spring design for such filter, delegating seems clunky. So testing altogether is I think your best bet.