# MIMEMessage and MIMEMessage mock test case fails with assertion error on EmailUtil

Tags: junit4, powermock, easymock

**What I'm trying to achieve** - Simple unit test for my EmailUtil which i have written for a Spring MVC application.
**Where I'm stuck** - Though i have mocked the MIMEmessage and JavaMailSender, test case failing in MimeMessageHelper.set**** methods.

Appreciate any help on this as I have tried few different ways even using PowerMock and no luck for last couple of days.

**EmailUtil.Java**

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;

import com.dashboard.domain.Attachment;
import com.dashboard.domain.Email;

public class EmailUtil {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailUtil.class
            .getName());

    /**
     * Private constructor to make sure that no one creating instance
     */
    private EmailUtil() {

    }

    /**
     * Functionality to send the mail. This method used the mail sender
     * configuration from spring-context file.
     * 
     * @param email
     * @param mailSender
     * @throws MessagingException
     */
    public static void sendEmail(JavaMailSender mailSender, Email email)
            throws MessagingException {

        LOGGER.info("Start of the method: sendEmail");
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        // use the true flag to indicate you need a multi part message
        boolean hasAttachments = email.getAttachments() != null
                && !email.getAttachments().isEmpty();
        LOGGER.info(" mimeMessage - {} ",mimeMessage);
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage,
                hasAttachments);
        LOGGER.info(" MimeMessageHelper - {} ",helper);
        helper.setTo(email.getTo());
        helper.setFrom(email.getFrom());
        helper.setCc(email.getCc());
        helper.setSubject(email.getSubject());
        helper.setText(email.getText(), true);

        List<Attachment> attachments = email.getAttachments();
        if (!attachments.isEmpty()) {
            for (Attachment attachment : attachments) {
                String filename = attachment.getFilename();
                DataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(
                        attachment.getData(), attachment.getMimeType());
                if (attachment.isInline()) {
                    helper.addInline(filename, dataSource);
                } else {
                    helper.addAttachment(filename, dataSource);
                }
            }
        }
        mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
        LOGGER.info("End of the method: sendEmail");
    }


}
```

**EmailUtilTest.Java**

```
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.expect;

import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.RecipientType;

import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.easymock.Mock;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;

import com.dashboard.domain.ApplicationConstant;
import com.dashboard.domain.Email;

/**
 * PowerMockDemo
 * @author s.arumugam
 *
 */
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(EmailUtil.class)
public class EmailUtilTest {

    Email email = new Email();

    @Mock
    JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Mock
    MimeMessage mimeMessage;

    @Mock
    MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper;

    @Before
    public void initList() {
        email.setFrom(ApplicationConstant.DEFAULT_MAIL_ID.getValue());
        email.setSubject("Subject");
        email.setTo("to.email@userdomain.com");
        email.setCc("admin@dashboard.com");
        email.setText("Body of the email"); 
    }

    @Test
    public void sendEmailTest() throws Exception{      
        mimeMessageHelper.setSubject(email.getSubject());
        mimeMessageHelper.setFrom(new InternetAddress(email.getFrom(), true));
        mimeMessageHelper.setCc(new InternetAddress(email.getCc()[0], true));
        mimeMessageHelper.setTo(new InternetAddress(email.getTo()[0], true));
        mimeMessageHelper.setText(email.getText());
        expect(javaMailSender.createMimeMessage()).andReturn(mimeMessage);
        Address sendTo[]={new InternetAddress(email.getTo()[0])};
        mimeMessage.setRecipients(RecipientType.TO,sendTo);
        EasyMock.expectLastCall().times(1);
        EasyMock.replay(mimeMessage);
        EasyMock.replay(javaMailSender);
        EmailUtil.sendEmail(javaMailSender, email);
        EasyMock.verify(mimeMessage);
        EasyMock.verify(javaMailSender);
    }

}
```

**Error Message:**

```
java.lang.AssertionError:    Unexpected method call MimeMessage.setRecipients(To, [to.email@userdomain.com]):
    MimeMessage.setRecipients(To, [to.email@userdomain.com]): expected: 1, actual: 0    at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:44)    at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:94)    at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:97)   at $javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a6025b60.setRecipients(<generated>)   at org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper.setTo(MimeMessageHelper.java:581)    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper.setTo(MimeMessageHelper.java:595)    at com.dashboard.util.EmailUtil.sendEmail(EmailUtil.java:50)
```

Comment: It's hard to help you because you haven't given us all the info. We need the `Attachment` and `Email` classes. We also need the dependencies used with their version ideally.

Comment: You should be more precise. Why are you using the PowerMock and Mockito tags for example? You should really really only use those tags that are relevant for your question!

Comment: @GhostCat - Where I had used Mockito? I have used only PowerMock and EasyMock.. if I understand correctly both can be used together for many purposes.

Comment: @Henri - Sorry for the delay in reply and I understand would have given domain classes as well. But I have fixed this now as I stated below and happy to hear if any drawbacks on the way I managed to fix it. If possible, can you help me with another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51121709/mocking-super-method-call-using-easymock-powermock

Comment: You had the *mockito* tag on your question?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ohh.. I managed to fix the issue.. purely by random trial and error..! That says I need to get into deep understanding of how these mock utils works.. Working test case below with a hope someone can find a complete working example with test case;

```
@RunWith(EasyMockRunner.class)
public class EmailUtilTest extends EasyMockSupport{

    @Mock
    JavaMailSender mailSender;

    @Mock
    MimeMessage mimeMessage;

    @Test
    public void testSendEmail() throws MessagingException{
        Email email = new Email();
        email.setFrom("from.email@dashboard.com");
        email.setSubject("Subject");
        email.setTo("to.email@userdomain.com");
        email.setCc("admin@dashboard.com");
        email.setText("Body of the email");
        EasyMock.expect(mailSender.createMimeMessage()).andReturn(mimeMessage);
        mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
        EasyMock.expectLastCall();
        EasyMock.replay(mailSender);
        EmailUtil.sendEmail(mailSender, email);
        EasyMock.verify(mailSender);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting `java.lang.AssertionError` is because EasyMock uses the `equals()` method to compare parameters passed to methods, and you cannot use `equals()` to compare arrays.

```
Address toAddress = new InternetAddress("a@b.com");
Address[] a1 = { toAddress };
Address[] a2 = { toAddress };
if (a1.equals(a2)) { // this will be false
    // so this won't happen
}
```

Thankfully, EasyMock provides us with several different argument matchers. In this case we should use `EasyMock.aryEq()`. So in order to mock out the call to `setRecipients()` method:

```
mimeMessage.setRecipients(EasyMock.eq(RecipientType.TO) , EasyMock.aryEq(sendTo));
```

I'm not sure how the accepted answer is working without changes to the `EmailUtil` class.